# MYSQL query winning streak including score

Tags: mysql

I have a query-generated table that counts up the winning streak as long as the player keeps winning. When  they player gets a positive score, the streak rises with 1, if he gets a negative score, the streak falls back to 0. The table looks like this:

```
+--------+------------------+--------+--------+
| player |    timestamp     | points | streak |
+--------+------------------+--------+--------+
| John   | 22/11/2012 23:01 |     -2 |      0 |
| John   | 22/11/2012 23:02 |      3 |      1 |
| John   | 22/11/2012 23:04 |      5 |      2 |
| John   | 22/11/2012 23:05 |     -2 |      0 |
| John   | 22/11/2012 23:18 |     15 |      1 |
| John   | 23/11/2012 23:20 |      5 |      2 |
| Chris  | 27/11/2012 22:12 |     20 |      1 |
| Chris  | 27/11/2012 22:14 |    -12 |      0 |
| Chris  | 27/11/2012 22:17 |      4 |      1 |
| Chris  | 27/11/2012 22:18 |     -4 |      0 |
| Chris  | 27/11/2012 22:20 |     10 |      1 |
| Chris  | 27/11/2012 22:21 |     20 |      2 |
| Chris  | 27/11/2012 22:22 |     90 |      3 |
+--------+------------------+--------+--------+
```

I would like to get the players maximum streak, which is easy to get ofcourse, but I would also like to include the points that the player scored in that particular streak. So, for the above example the result would have to look like this:

```
+--------+--------+-----------+
| player | points | maxstreak |
+--------+--------+-----------+
| John   |     20 |         2 |
| Chris  |    120 |         3 |
+--------+--------+-----------+
```

Any idea's of how I could achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `order` in result set you have presented? I can't see how one would be able to tell `Chris|10|1` from `Chris|20|1`, which should be parts of different streaks.

Comment: the order is made by the insert_id, a timestamp. I could include that if needed.

Comment: i'm not sure exactly how you would do this but i would first go about making additional tables to hold specifically the max streak and points values, this would then create a relation between the tables which would give you a place to start then within this table make streak -> streak_id and points points_id then this would make it able to be transferred across the tables (all these tables should have id field). this is just my thought process so dont quote me if i'm wrong :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not had a chance to actually try this, but is SHOULD work using mySQL Variables...

At the beginning, the inner-most query just queries from your scores table and forces the data in order of player and timestamp.  From that, I have to process sequentially with MySQL variables.  First thing... on each new record being processed, if I am on a different "Player" (which should ACTUALLY be based on an ID instead of name), I am resetting the streak, points, maxStreak, maxStreakPoints to zero, THEN setting the last user to whoever its about to process.

Immediately after that, I am checking for the streak status, points, etc...

Once all have been tabulated, I then use the OUTERMOST query to get on a per-player basis, what their highest max streak / max streak points.

```
SELECT
      Final.Player,
      MAX( Final.MaxStreak ) MaxStreak,
      MAX( Final.MaxStreakPoints ) MaxStreakPoints 
   FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT 
              PreOrd.Player,
              PreOrd.TimeStamp,
              PreOrd.Points,
              @nStreak       := case when PreOrd.Points < 0 then 0
                                     when PreOrd.Player = @cLastPlayer then @nStreak +1
                                     else 1 end  Streak,                              

              @nStreakPoints := case when @nStreak = 1 then PreOrd.Points
                                     when @nStreak > 1 then @nStreakPoints + PreOrd.Points
                                     else 0 end  StreakPoints,

              @nMaxStreak    := case when PreOrd.Player != @cLastPlayer then @nStreak
                                     when @nStreak > @nMaxStreak then @nStreak
                                     else @nMaxStreak end MaxStreak,

              @nMaxStreakPoints := case when PreOrd.Player != @cLastPlayer then @nStreakPoints
                                        when @nStreak >= @nMaxStreak and @nStreakPoints > @nMaxStreakPoints then @nStreakPoints
                                        else @nMaxStreakPoints end MaxStreakPoints,

              @cLastPlayer := PreOrd.Player PlayerChange
         FROM 
              ( select
                      S.Player,
                      S.TimeStamp,
                      S.Points
                   from 
                      Scores2 S
                   ORDER BY 
                      S.Player,
                      S.TimeStamp,
                      S.`index` ) PreOrd,
              ( select
                      @nStreak := 0,
                      @nStreakPoints := 0,
                      @nMaxStreak := 0,
                      @nMaxStreakPoints := 0,
                      @cLastPlayer := '~' ) SQLVars
      ) as Final
   group by 
      Final.Player
```

Now, this could give a false max streak points, such that on a single score the person has 90 points, then a streak of 1 for 10 points, 2 for 10 points, 3 for 10 points, 30 total.. Still thinking on that though... :)

Here's what I get when I add the `index` column as you've made available from data supplied
[image]

[SQL Fiddle Showing my solution...](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/544a4/4)

Comment: thank you so much for putting the time and effort in this. Seems a bit too complicated for my limited SQL knowledge though. When I try to run this I get the error of a duplicate name for "ignoreStreak" and "ignoreStreakPoints". Hwne changing those to for example "ignoreMaxStreak" and "ignoreMaxStreakPoints", the code runs, but the output seems not to be correct. I Get all "0" values in the MaxStreak column and the MaxStreakPoints seem not to be correct. I really appreciate your effort, thanks.

Comment: @Roddeh, the revised query works... However, the innermost "FROM" uses table "Scores2", so you may need to change that.

Comment: DRapp, thanks again! The MaxStreak values are correct, however when I check the MaxStreakPoints, still something is not right, it doens't seem to count all scores within the streak correctly. About a half 2/3 of the times, the value is correct. I can't really find a pattern in it. I made an excel file to illustrate it with the real data: https://www.wetransfer.com/dl/OVQCiTUO/d3cd2c518837886f19d88a577e787241428777ddd8523366aa9066e4539b842de08f9b3b6c26a38

Comment: @Roddeh, I'll try to test with data later tonight after work.  Just getting up now.

Comment: @Roddeh, I tried with your data in the exact same order as you provided and it worked.  THE ONLY CHANGE I had to make was to add to the inner-most order by clause MY auto-increment column.  If you too have such auto-increment for your actual table, add that.  If no such, it was due to the same exact times on them that appear to let the engine pick whichever it wants first for returning the data.  Check out your set and let me know.  To confirm proper return order try "select * from yourTable where Player='Arne' order by player, timestamp ... let me know what YOU get WITHOUT the auto-inc column

Comment: DRapp, with or without the auto-increment I get the exact same output. I would find it odd that I would get a different result, since the order is done by the timestamp already and I see no other way the table could be sorted differently. All timestamps are unique for each player. With the "inner most order" you mean this one:  ORDER BY 
                      S.Player,
                      S.TimeStamp. Right? English is not my native language, so maybe I don't get it right.

Comment: I added a second file in which all my data and queries are, the base table, the temporary table (auto-increment included) on which I run your query, and the according results. Thank you so much for the effort you already put in this! http://wtrns.fr/2KjTqSDF2ARJOc3

Comment: @Roddeh, See revision, and posting out to SQLFiddle at the very end too.  I knew I wasn't crazy on the approach :)

Comment: Man, you're amazing. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out with this! I'm so grateful!

Comment: Still have a little request (if I may ofc). I would like to know the timestamp of the moment that the maxstreak was reached. If I include the timestamp in the last select statement, it gives me the very first timestamp of each player record.

Comment: @Roddeh, I would like you to follow the sample... Create another variable in the list as a date/time, and just like the maxStreakPoints criteria, set the new maxStreakDate... just ensure its done BEFORE you set the value for the last "user"

Comment: @Roddeh, great, now you understand the basics to mysql vars.. You can also consider it like a LOOP in a program and each atVariable:= is like a sequential line number in the program.  So once set, you can use it for subsequent line tests.

Comment: yes I learned a lot with that. Still... I unfortunately discovered a 'mistake' that has nothing to do with the timestamp. The problem is the MaxStreakPoints column. Lets say you get a streak of 2 and have 50 points then the maxstreakpoints value is set to 50, which is correct at that piont, but imagine that after that the player scores a streak of 3 but only manages to get 20 point in that streak, then the maxstreakvalue should change to that value. Now we select the max value of the maxstreakpoints, but that's not always correct, since you can score a bigger streak with less points.

Comment: @ DRapp,I inserted some extra values in the example to illustrate the above. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8275b/1/1 Look for player 'Bjorg'. He gets a score of 90 with a streak of 1, later on when he gets a streak of 3 the MaxStreakPoints should become 6+2+18 = 26 and not 90, since that score was reached in a shorter streak.

Comment: I managed to resolve the issue by altering the MaxstreakPoints var and creating 2 temporary tables. Then join those 2 and get the wanted result! I'm proud to have found the answer myself :D

Comment: @Roddeh, sorry couldnt respond before you solved yourself (gone for weekend)... however, it is great that you did too.  Good job.

Comment: no worries m8, glad I could solve it myself. Hope you had a good weekend ;)

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to store additional information when you calculate the streak.  For instance, you could store the time stamp when the streak began.

A less-serious recommendation is to switch to another database, that supports window functions.  This would be much easier.

The approach is to find when the streak began and then sum up everything between that time and the max streak.  To do this, we'll use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select max(timestamp) from t t2 where t2.timestamp <= t.timestamp and t2.player = t.player and t2.streak = 0
       ) as StreakStartTimeStamp
from t
where t.timeStamp = (select max(streak) from t t2 where t.player = t2.player)
```

Now, we will embed this query as a subquery, so we can add the appropriate times:

```
select t.player,
       sum(s.points)
from t join
     (select t.*,
             (select max(timestamp) from t t2 where t2.timestamp <= t.timestamp and t2.player = t.player and t2.streak = 0
             ) as StreakStartTimeStamp
      from t
      where t.streak = (select max(streak) from t t2 where t.player = t2.player)
     ) s
     on t.player = s.player
group by t.player
```

I haven't tested this query, so there are probably some syntax errors.  However, the approach should work.  You may want to have indexes on the table, on streak and timestamp for performance reasons.